# How to use [dvipscolor]xcolor in tikzposter

Tags: color, tikzposter

I'd like to change the colour of my tikzposter to be the "Blue" colour from the `dvipscolor` option of the `xcolor` package.  Would someone please tell me how to do this?

```
 \documentclass[25pt, landscape]{tikzposter} 
 \geometry{paperwidth=24in, paperheight=36in}

\usetheme{Simple}
\colorlet{backgroundcolor}{white}
\colorlet{titlebgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{titlefgcolor}{blue} % <------------ This is the one I'd like to change!
\useblockstyle[]{Basic}% titleleft to left align title
 
\title{Maintenance Management Plan}
\author{engineering}

% -------------------------------------------- This determines margins
 \makeatletter
 \setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
 \setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}
\maketitle

  \block{}{
  \begin{tabular}{c p{21.5 cm} p{30 cm} |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 \#  & \textbf{Equipment} & \textbf{Description of Maintenance Requirements} & \textbf{JAN} & \textbf{FEB} & \textbf{MAR} & \textbf{APR} & \textbf{MAY} & \textbf{JUN} & \textbf{JUL} & \textbf{AUG} & \textbf{SEP} & \textbf{OCT} & \textbf{NOV} & \textbf{DEC} \\ 
 \hline \hline
 1&  dosing pumps: verification & Quarterly verification of seals and hoses. (see manual). & X & & & X& & & X& & &X & &  \\
 2 &Some other stuff...  &      &  & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
 3&  &      &  & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
 \hline \hline
 
  \end{tabular}
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Either `\documentclass[..., dvipsnames]{tikzposter}` or `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} \documentclass ...` works.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The correct optionname is `dvipsnames`. use it as documentclass option like this:

```
\documentclass[25pt, landscape, dvipsnames]{tikzposter} % <=============
\geometry{paperwidth=24in, paperheight=36in}

\usetheme{Simple}

\colorlet{backgroundcolor}{white}
\colorlet{titlebgcolor}{white}
\colorlet{titlefgcolor}{Blue} % <=======================================
\useblockstyle[]{Basic}% titleleft to left align title
 
\title{Maintenance Management Plan}
\author{engineering}

% -------------------------------------------- This determines margins
 \makeatletter
 \setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
 \setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}
\maketitle

  \block{}{
  \begin{tabular}{c p{21.5 cm} p{30 cm} |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 \#  & \textbf{Equipment} & \textbf{Description of Maintenance Requirements} & \textbf{JAN} & \textbf{FEB} & \textbf{MAR} & \textbf{APR} & \textbf{MAY} & \textbf{JUN} & \textbf{JUL} & \textbf{AUG} & \textbf{SEP} & \textbf{OCT} & \textbf{NOV} & \textbf{DEC} \\ 
 \hline \hline
 1&  dosing pumps: verification & Quarterly verification of seals and hoses. (see manual). & X & & & X& & & X& & &X & &  \\
 2 &Some other stuff...  &      &  & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
 3&  &      &  & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
 \hline \hline
 
  \end{tabular}
  }

\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf file:

[image]

Comment: This works well, but produces an error.  Please see last comment for \PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} idea.  Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: @cmp which error? Show it completly in your question, please. With my current MiKTeX I get no error message ...

Comment: The error is actually a "Warning" (so not actually an error!). It says the following for the both of them:  "Unknown Option dvipsnames" and "Unused global option(s):[dvipsnames].  I'm not sure why it gives these errors, but it seems that using the \PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} works splendidly.  Thanks in any case for your effort in answering the question.  It certainly was a step in the right direction.